# Is it possible to do speech to text over a long period of time?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I want to be able to record an arbitrarily long conversation on Android and have it translated into text. For example if you have a 20 minute conversation with a friend it should record both sides of the entire conversation.

Is this possible with the [Speech](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html) classes or would I need to do something like [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder.html) and translate it to text with a third party service?

My concern with the speech class is that it is primarily used for single commands as opposed to longer conversations.

Comment: `My concern with the speech class is that it is primarily used for single commands` So, you never used it for dictation?

Comment: I haven't actually used it that way yet, it's possible that you can dictate for long terms and that this is a dumb question! (Sorry if that's the case)

Comment: It's not a dumb question. I answered by experience. Since I'm able to let the OS write what I say (I have big fingers, and the keyboard is sometimes just too small). But I don't know how long it can hold continuous speech and I don't know which is the actual time threshold before "it gets tired of hearing my annoying voice"... ;)

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's my primary concern what the threshold is.

Comment: Something near 1-2 seconds, I guess. Wait! I actually meant the silence-threshold. I do mean the pauses between sentences.

Comment: Ah yeah, that wouldn't work for my use case then. I'll dig into it a bit more but sounds like I may have to use MediaRecorder.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean for a silence threshold. Since I'm aiming to record a conversation I'd definitely need to extend this. Ideally with a "Record" and "Stop Recording" button.

Comment: Maybe it could be done in 3 phases. **1** - Record your speech. **2** - Identify the silences and reduce them to about .5 s. **3** - Do the speech recognition stuff on the cleaned-up file.